# winsock component

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, winsock

i have a winsock component made with vb.net in a class library that has events.

how do i make it appear in tool box if i reference the dll in another project.?

How do i use it in my c# program?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want it in a toolbox? What about writing code by hand?

Comment: i wnat it in toolbox so that drag and drop in a form, or you can tell me how do do it by code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a proper component that's been registered properly on your PC you can just right click on the ToolBox and select *Choose Toolbox Items* which gives you the dialog described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyca0t6t%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Otherwise, just add a reference to the class and create some eventhandlers. Just search google for *custom eventhandlers c#* and you should find plenty of samples/tutorial, for example [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers) link looks like it shows it in a nice and easy way.